# Calculate total of observation per variable in R

Tags: r, database, dataset

In STATA there is a command where you can calculate the total number of observations per variable.
For example: let's consider "`a`" a binary variable (0/1).

[image]

If you use the command `tab` in STATA then this summarizes the number of observations for each possibility of the variable

[image]

Is there a similar command in **R**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `count()` counts each level of your vector `a` and you can quickly compute share and cumulative share by hand like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  a = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
)

df |> 
  count(a) |> 
  mutate(
    share = n / sum(n),
    cum_share = cumsum(share)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>       a     n share cum_share
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     0     2   0.4       0.4
#> 2     1     3   0.6       1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Just wrap this code in a function if you find yourself looking for the full Stata output often.

Comment: `janitor::tabyl(df$a)` is another shortcut for the count and share, though it doesn't include the cumulative column.

Answer (score 1):

Since OP didn't mention that they needed the cumulative column, maybe worth mentioning the simple base R `table` command, which shows the count of observations of each value. This code:

```
table(mtcars$vs)
```

Will output:

```
 0  1 
18 14
```

because the binary column `vs` from the dataframe `mtcars` has 18 instances of 0 and 14 instances of 1.